# Detect and handle actions in WKWebView (iOS-Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

[image: Preview in my case (view in WKWebView)]

Is there a solution or the right code to solve when I press the download button on the image I attached, it is saved directly to the user library.

- besides adding Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in info.plist

For the current condition, when the download button is pressed I can only throw it into the safari browser then the user downloads from there, as follows:

[image]

With code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            let urlString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
            if urlString?.contains("https://photoframe") ?? false {
                if let url = URL(string: urlString ?? "") {
                    if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated && !(navigationAction.request.url?.host?.lowercased().hasPrefix("\(url)"))! {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
```

And of course it's less effective

by the way, what I want to save in the library is in the form of a url in WKWebView, for example:
https://photoframe/result//2021/01/e83999b6d507a6efcce73e80c737c98c.png

Thank you in advance, I will appreciate any answer ;)

Comment: You can probably use webView.evaluateJavaScript to inject javascript code, which run when the button is clicked and from that retrieve the url of the image.

Comment: Thanks @SumeshSivan I'll try it first